# Loading google font with Next.js in Bootstrap

Tags: next.js, bootstrap-5, vercel, next.js13

I would like to load google font as described here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/font-optimization

If I'm following the docs and loading like this, it's all good:

```
import { Open_Sans } from '@next/font/google';

const openSans = Open_Sans ({
    subsets: ['latin']
})

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <main className={openSans.className}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </main>
    )
}

export default MyApp
```

This version is making load the font and generates a class name, something like this:

```
.__className_d8c39e {
    font-family: '__Open_Sans_d8c39e', '__Open_Sans_Fallback_d8c39e';
    font-style: normal;
}
```

But instead of this, if it's possible, I would like to use Bootstrap CSS variable, as I defined with `$font-family-sans-serif: "Open Sans";` in my custom `_variables.scss`, so Bootstrap will render on the frontend like `:root{--bs-font-sans-serif: "Open Sans";}`.

I also know I can use variable in next, like:

```
const openSans = Open_Sans ({
    subsets: ['latin'],
    variable: '--bs-font-sans-serif'
})

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <main className={openSans.variable}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </main>
    )
}
```

but this will just create another class name with the given variable name:

```
.__variable_d8c39e {
    --bs-font-sans-serif: '__Open_Sans_d8c39e', '__Open_Sans_Fallback_d8c39e';
}
```

Can't I just not add the className, but still use the optimised google font somehow in Bootstrap source file?

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. I have worked with a CSS variable:

```
const openSans = Open_Sans ({
    subsets: ['latin'],
    variable: '--body-font'
})

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <main className={openSans.variable}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </main>
    )
}
```

The main container now has the variable --body-font at its disposal, which refers to the font family. I then tried to use this in Bootstrap:

```
$font-family-sans-serif: var(--body-font);
```

**Unfortunately this doesn't work**, because the CSS variable of Bootstrap `--bs-body-font-family` is already defined in `:root` and the CSS variable of *next/font* is only assigned in the main container.

I have now solved the whole thing via a workaround by defining the attribute font-family in the main container (the CSS variable is available here):

```
main {
    font-family: var(--body-font);
}
```

Thus, I only overwrite the bootstrap style. Unfortunately, there seems to be no other solution.

Comment: Yeah, I had the same conclusion, unfortunately. It's a shame though.

Comment: I just treid with the new beta version of Nextjs, and you can define font-family on the body as well, so I just added `--bs-body-font-family` as a variable name and it worked.